# $b_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$, when does the comparison test not work?

Tags: calculus

Consider the following *sequences*:
$$c_n=1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$b_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$$

If I were to use the limit comparison theorem and use $c_n$ to compare to $b_n$ ($c_n$ satisfies the conditions of being $>0$, so it works), then for which values of $p$ does the limit comparison theorem NOT work? Again, I'm asking for when the theorem does **not** work, with the only value that changes being $p$. Well, in this case, there are 3 considerations:

- Limit of $\frac{b_n}{c_n} \not =0$. Then $b_n$ would have to diverge here, so $p<=1$
- Limit of $\frac{b_n}{c_n} =0$. In this case either $c_n$ has to diverge or that $b_n$ has to converge. But $c_n$ does not diverge. That leaves us with only one case with $b_n$ diverging, so again $p <=1$.
- Limit of $\frac{b_n}{c_n} DNE$ (diverges to infinity), then $b_n$ would have to diverge, or $c_n$ diverges.

All in all, the only case where the limit comparison test does not work is when $p < 1$. At least from what I concluded. Are there any other values that I forgot?

Comment: I don't follow this. $1-\cos{\frac1n}\sim\frac1{2n^2}$ as $n\to\infty$, from the Taylor series for $\cos$

Comment: So what values of p would not work?

Comment: Can someone please help me out here?